# Searching an array from bottom to top

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a table array `$E$14:$G$851`. Column E just contains unique identifiers, lets say a/b/c/d etc, column F contains hundreds of numbers all less than or equal to 20 and column G contains the values I need returned.

I need a formula which will search for the unique identifier in column E, and then search **UP** column F and find me the FIRST value that is LESS THAN the column F result and use that result to return the adjacent value in column G.

So if I had searched for "g", the formula would then search **UP** column F for the first number LESS THAN 16. This would be "d" with 12. the formula would then return 25010 from column G.

[image: example]

I've been searching for an answer to this for weeks and haven't found any examples of excel searching an array from bottom to top. I'd strongly prefer to not change the data layout (such as flipping it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it with the following array formula (press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after entering it in the cell:

`=INDEX(C:C,MAX(IF(OFFSET($B$1,0,0,MATCH(E1,A:A,0)-1)<VLOOKUP(E1,A:B,2,FALSE),ROW(OFFSET(B1,0,0,MATCH(E1,A:A,0)-1)),"")))`

How it works:

- `OFFSET($B$1,0,0,MATCH(E1,A:A,0)-1)` - gets a reference of B column over the ID being searched
- `IF(OFFSET(...)<VLOOKUP(E1,A:B,2,FALSE),ROW(OFFSET(...),"")` - returns an array containing row number for rows having value in B less then row searched and blank for the others
- `MAX(IF(...))` - select maximum value (last row with value in B fullfilling criteria
- `=INDEX(C:C,MAX(...))` - select cell in column C

[image]

Comment: – Very nice, except when I set E1 to `a`, the result is `#REF!`.

Comment: Gee this formula is complex! 
Works great for this given example, but are you able to help me with moving around the data source location? I assume that it is the MATCH function which is giving me trouble, but if the table array A1:C9 is moved down the formula will no longer work as intended.

So lets say for the table array of $E$14:$G$851. Is it simply the -1 on the end of the Match that will need to change or am I missing more?

Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Sorry no I got that working, just had to reduce the ROW value first.
What about if I was to search for next lowest result? How would I incorporate SMALL in here, in order to return, say, 3993? (from your example ie cell C3 rather than C4)

Comment: If you want to find second result from the bottom, then instead of MAX you need to use `LARGE (...,2)`

Comment: @creidhne: result for that case isn't defined in the question, so getting an error I think is fine.

Comment: you're a smart cookie! Thanks for the help Mate! works like a charm

Comment: @MátéJuhász : Ah actually unfortunately LARGE will not discriminate between equal values in column B. So if you were to enter H as the search criteria the formula will return C5 as the result, rather than C4 as it should if it is searching for the second lowest number. Any way to fix?

Comment: Did you set second parameter of LARGE to 2?

Comment: @MátéJuhász
I did yep.
This is the formula with LARGE 

=INDEX($C$1:$C$12,LARGE(IF(OFFSET($B$1,0,0,MATCH(E1,$A$1:$A$12,0)-1)<VLOOKUP(E1,$A$1:$B$12,2,FALSE),ROW(OFFSET(B1,0,0,MATCH(E1,$A$1:$A$12,0)-1)),""),2))

Answer (score 0):

In the example, the column with the result is G, but what's the correct row? If we can find the row, then `INDIRECT("G"&row)` will get the result.

[image: worksheet]

A solution is to add a column of pointers as column H. Each pointer is the row for `INDIRECT` and `VLOOKUP` can find it. Cell `C2` has the formula.

```
=INDIRECT("G"&VLOOKUP(B2,$E$1:$H$9,4,FALSE))
```

So now, searching backwards is reduced to a `VLOOKUP` for a pointer to the result. How to generate column H? I haven't yet found a way with Excel formulas alone, but here are a few ideas.

If column F rarely changes, then a few lines of perl or python with a copy and paste is all that's needed. I used perl. If column F is more frequently updated, then VBA might work. Alternatively, perl can read the data from the main Excel file and generate a second workbook to use as an external source.

The pointers avoid the need flip the data or change the data layout. The tricky backward search is done one-time by perl or VBA, and `VLOOKUP` is quick, simple and easy to test.